# I need to get the answer that is 1 above my query search

Tags: google-apps-script, google-query-language

I have an equation that goes into a column and searches for the first 0, the column tracks the progress of things in 1s and 0s, problem is that setting it to find 1 only returns the top most value, I would either need this to find the and return the top most 0 +1 cell above or to search bottom up.
I need it to return the string in the corresponding cell.

```
=QUERY(A3:D,"Select A where D = 0 limit 1",0)
```

This hasn't worked for me, I have not been able to find a way to either invert the search to bottom up or to simply grab the string in the cell above the first 0 found in the list.

Comment: Can you clarify more the question by providing screenshots of your source data and the expected output? Therefore, we'll be able to reproduce on our end.

Comment: I cannot due to an NDA around the data itself,
the best I can do is try to describe better.

Basically there is a row that has certain stages of completion, I am dynamically pulling what stage is complete from a different document and then filling out if the stage is complete in a column that either has a 1 for complete or a 0 for incomplete
I am then looking for the lowest 1 on the column and grabbing the associated stage name to display .
=QUERY(A3:D,"Select A where D = 0 limit 1",0)
In this case A3:A has the stage names and D3:D has either a 0 or a 1 going in order.

Comment: I have limit 1 so that it only displays the first found 0 since it searches by default in a descending order. Sine I don't know how to change it to search from the bottom of the range to the top, rather then the default top to bottom. Since I am grabbing the first 0 in the list and want to display the last 1 in the list which would by proxy be the cell above, it needs to either grab the cell above the target or search the bottom of the range to the top of the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, if you're only trying to get Column `A`:-

```
=QUERY(A3:D,"Select A where D = 0 offset "&COUNTA(A3:A) ,0)
```

**Reference:-**

[Offset](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#offset)